# iOS + Rails: Login with Facebook best practice

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm building an iOS app with a Rails backend. The user can log into the iOS app with Facebook.

What is the best way to associate this with a User record on the backend?

My thinking is to get the Facebook UID, check if a record exists with that ID in the Users table and if not create an account by storing the UID and Facebook email. Is this the correct way this should be done?

I haven't written a system like this before so I want to make sure I'm not going about it completely the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: You want a user to sign up with facebook only or do you want them to sign up with email as well as facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you might want to check out parse.com as a backend service

But either way what you suggested is pretty much how they are implementing it and they were acquired by Facebook so I believe they do it right:

add a column called 'fuid' to store the Facebook ID and check if such an entry exists before adding a new user entry to the User table

Comment: Thanks. I've used Parse before but decided to go my own way this time. Should I get the user to create a password or is that unnecessary?

Comment: unnecessary but make sure you create a Facebook access token column as well

Comment: Is that to store Facebook's access token?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) will be a good way to start from. For the database of app you can create an authentication table where you can store the type of authentication(in case you change your mind and want to sign up users from twitter or somewhere else), uid and the access token. You will also need a users table where you can store all the information related to a user. Not to forget a user will have many authentications or one authentication depending on your need.

As for the flow of app you can go two ways:

a. You get the users approval from the facebook, store access token, uid and get users email, first name or whatever information you need and then store it all in the back end and then sign up him/her.

b. Get the approval from user, store uid and access token and then render a form which will be filled with the user's information like first name,last name etc. User will create a password for your app and then you can sign up him/her.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually watched a few Railscasts including that one. As I'm doing the authentication on iOS and using the Facebook SDK I don't think I need to store the access token as the SDK seems to store a copy and log me in automatically each time the app is launched. I actually originally went with the way you're describing but ended up not needing any of the auth on the rails side as iOS is the only client.